# How can I pull a git folder to a new computer using my ssh key?

Tags: git

I have git on a computer that I'll call Mac1, and access through an ssh key to a folder on my uni's server that I'll call ProjectName.

I want to pull this folder to another computer that I'll call Mac2. On Mac2, I've installed git and told it my username and email address using `git config`.

How can I do pull ProjectName to Mac2?

Comment: How is this related to `git`?

Comment: Please be more precise, use terms such as *remote* and *repository* as appropriate. Perhaps you mean `rsync` instead?

Comment: Ha! Good point, I assumed he meant ssh access to the remote git repo.

Comment: I don't know what an `rsync` is. I am just asking a question on a basic level. @aet you assumed correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a good way: create a new public/private keypair, and have the new public key added to the git server.

There is a not as good way: copy the private key from computer 1 to computer 2.

Comment: By default, with openssh, your private key will be in ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Comment: Thanks for the info. Can you see any reason why my uni (who manage the server) would want me (or any other user) to be do one, and only one, of the above options? Are they likely to want me to only have one private key for example?

Comment: Universities and corporations often have inane policies for reasons that are important to someone. The question is, how difficult is it to get a new key added? With a system like github, it is easy for you to do that yourself, and so I would say use the option of generating a new keypair, if it is difficult to get a new key added, just copy your private key, and get back to coding.

Comment: Mmm... thanks for your (assuming) insight! I'll ask an admin just to be sure. I don't want to screw up on my first week.

Answer (score 0):

```
git clone ssh://username@Mac1/path/to/your.git
```

unless you really want to let no password access from Mac2, on Mac2 `cat id_rsa.pub.Mac1 >> .ssh/authorized_keys`